# Is ZFC - Foundation + NoCycles finitely axiomatizable relative to ZFC - Foundation?

Tags: set-theory

This is a follow-up question to [Does the nonexistence of $\in$-cycles imply the nonexistence of an infinite descending $\in$-sequence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4519567/does-the-nonexistence-of-in-cycles-imply-the-nonexistence-of-an-infinite-desc). In that question, I discussed a theory which the answerer called ZFC - Foundation + NoCycles. It is gotten from ZFC - Foundation by adding an infinite set of axioms that prohibit membership cycles, like $x \in x$, $x \in y \in x$, etc. My question is, is that theory finitely axiomatizable relative to the base theory of ZFC - Foundation? That is, do you have to add only finitely many axioms to ZFC - Foundation to get the same theory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add the axiom that there is no function whose domain is a natural number and defines a cycle.

This has the added benefit that the length of the cycle is also not allowed to be any non-standard integer either.

---

If you just want to talk about cycles that are meta-finite, this is of course not finitely axiomatisable. If $M_n$ is a model of $\sf ZFC$ without Foundations with "there is a least cycle with length $n$", then their ultraproduct by a free ultrafilter on the natural numbers is a model in which there are no meta-finite cycles, but internally-finite cycles will exist.

Comment: This might overshoot, though (precisely beacuse of the "added benefit") ...

Comment: Overshoot for the moon, hit the stars. Isn't that what they say? Funny enough, since it's consistent that any cycle is at least of length $n$, taking an ultrapower of such models gives us no cycles of stantard length but cycles of non-standard length!

Comment: (Which may or may not answer the OP's question to the negative. I will add that when I get home.)

Comment: Yeah, Noah Schweber is right. I want to have a finite set of axioms that give me the same theory as ZFC - Foundation + NoCycles, not a stronger theory.

Comment: @user107952: But the question is what does "finite cycle" mean. Internally finite or meta-finite?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Since they're using a scheme (see the linked question), it's clear that actually-finite is meant.

Comment: Re: the edit, I don't think that's entirely clear. Why is it obvious that, for each specific (meta)finite $n$, there is a model of $\mathsf{ZFC-Found}$ with a finite $\in$-cycle but no $\in$-cycles of length $\le n$? I don't think that's hard to show, but it's not quite trivial.

Answer (score -1):

$\forall n\in\omega \setminus \{0\}\,\neg\,\exists f:(n+1)\to V ...$

$ ...(\,f(n)\in f(0)\land\,\forall j\in n\,( f(j)\in f(j+1)\,)).$

When defining "function", I prefer the Kuratowski ordered-pair $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}.$ Because if we define $(a,b)=\{a,\{a,b\}\}$ then in the absence of Foundation, I don't know whether $(a,b)=(c,d)$ implies $(a=c\land b=d).$

Comment: This is exactly the same as Asaf's answer, just with more symbols. In particular, it has the same problem: it overshoots by ruling out nonstandard length "cycles."